# Element embedding Flutter in HTML based webpage?

Tags: html, flutter, embedding

Now that Element Embedding is out on Flutter 3.10. Instead of adding Flutter content to the webpage, is it possible to just add the Flutter widgets/components? For example, `ElevatedButton()`.

What I mean by not adding Flutter content is that I don't want to add the [whole app](https://imgur.com/a/9nMDuYq) (counter app on the right). I just wanted to add just the widgets itself.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be not possible I guess...